# mvn clean install Could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven

```
Could not find artifact oswego-concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4-jboss-update1 in gtrepositories  -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

What does this mean? How do I correct this? Does this mean that file is missing in the repo? I find that hard to believe because lots of people use jboss with maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is it's down at the moment. Try adding an alternative repository featuring that artifact to your pom.xml, such as MvnRepository:

```
[...]
<repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>mvnrepository.com</id>
       <name>MVN Repository</name>
       <url>http://mvnrepository.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
[...]
```